# play framework 2.7 form with table data with pagination is submitting nulls except the displaying page

Tags: playframework, play-framework-2.7

I am using play framework 2.7 where i am using form that renders a table with some input fields.
upon editing the table fields and submitting, only the current displaying page is getting submitted correctly. all previous and next page objects are coming as null.

Is there any option to get all the table objects without nulls?

Comment: How is the pagination implemented?

Comment: I used jquery datatable plugin